# sum certain columns of 2 tables matching criteria sql

Tags: mysql

Table1 data:

```
ACType Dualhr P1hr Total 
A320     2     2    4
B787     1     2    3
B777     3     1    4
```

Table2 data:

```
ACType P1hr Total

A320    5     5
```

on comparing the 2 tables,what sql query will give me result:

```
ACType Dualhr P1hr Total 
A320     2     7     9
B787     1     2     3
B777     3     1     4
```

which should also factor case when Table1 is empty,so to give result:

```
ACType Dualhr P1hr Total 
A320     0      5    5
```

Comment: Start with UNION, and see how you get on

Comment: Why do b787 and b777 drop out of your second result example?

Comment: @p.salmon because table1 is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use union and subquery:

```
select ACType, sum(Dualhr) as Dualhr, sum(P1hr) as P1hr,sum(Total) as Total 
from
(
select ACType, Dualhr, P1hr, Total from table1
union all
select ACType, 0, P1hr, Total from table2)a
group by ACType
```

Comment: which case those are, explain and if this answer helps you then please accept this

Comment: Thanks. In some cases,  Table2 may not have few columns that are present in Table1. For eg here, P1hr is present..in other case, only Dualhr is present.  columns are lesser in number in Table2 than Table1...in actual ptogram, I have 14 columns in Table1 and 7 in Table2...So at one time all 7 columns will not be filled in Table2

Comment: what if the query has " select ACType, Dualhr, P1hr, Total from table2" ?

Comment: your table2 does not have Dualhr column

Comment: so columns not being used in table2 will be referred by 0 in the query?

Comment: yes that is the way to show columns which are not present in table